# VBA Calculate a range of cells after copying and pasting formulas

Tags: vba, excel

I have a working VBA function which copies the formulas from a range of cells and requests where the user wants to paste. Once the function has pasted into the specified row(s), I have included the .Calculate function to update the formulas.
However, when the .Calculate runs, it updates only the range that the user has inputted, and not the entire row.
With the code below, assume that A2 is a forename, B2 is a surname and C2:E2 are formulas. When the input box comes up requesting where to paste, the user could select C3:E3 and would calculate everything. However if they just lazily click C3, and the formulas are pasted in, it will only update C3.
How do I amend this?

```
    Sub PasteMacro()

'
' PasteMacro Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+m
'
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Ret = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please select a range where you want to paste", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not Ret Is Nothing Then
        Selection.Copy

        Range("C2:E2").Copy Destination:=Ret

        Ret.Calculate

            Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
End Sub
```

-------------A -------       B  -----------------       C       --------------------             D       -----------------------         E
1 ---------------------------------------- 56   --------------------   66    --------------------- 76
2   ------Andrew    ----M   ----------=SUM(D1:E1)   -------- =SUM(E1:F1)    -------- =SUM(F1:G1)
3   -------- John    ----       S
Say you have the following excel table. You run the macro and click on C3 instead of typing C3:E3.
The macro will paste the formulas from C2:E2 into C3:E3. The problem is that because only one cell (C3) was clicked upon, the .Calculate function will only update that cell and not the range  C3:E3.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem using simple formulas and your code.  If @bonCodigo suggestion does not work, please provide more details -- in particular, the formulas and precedents you are copy/pasting

Comment: I have added some extra information to the bottom of my query. bonCodigo's answer is not what I am looking for.

Comment: There are no formulas being pasted into `C3:E3` by your code and method.  Your code pastes information from `C1:E1` which consists only of constants.

Comment: Just amended my code to fit with my example. Range is C2:E2.

Comment: See my Answer -- it seems you probably have calculation mode set to manual.

Comment: Ok great, I'll give it a go thanks. I negated to mention that my spread sheet has calculations as manual, because I have thousands of formulas running within the spread sheet. Updating the entirety would take a very long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to reproduce your problem, I must set `Calculation` to `Manual`.  I cannot reproduce your problem if `Calculation` is `Automatic`.

Assuming you only want to recalculate the destination cells that match the copied cells, I would suggest a minor modification in your code, to ensure the destination is calculated.  Also, depending on your goals, it might be well to protect the sheet so that only cells in column C can be selected, or that you use the selected Row as the destination and hard code the columns.

For example:

Option Explicit

```
Sub PasteMacro()
Dim Ret As Range
Dim RangeToCopy As Range

Set RangeToCopy = Range("C2:F2")
'
' PasteMacro Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+m
'
    Set Ret = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please select a range where you want to paste", Type:=8)
    If Not Ret Is Nothing Then    
        RangeToCopy.Copy Destination:=Ret    
        Ret.Resize(1, RangeToCopy.Columns.Count).Calculate

            Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
End Sub
```

or even:

```
Option Explicit
Sub PasteMacro()
Dim Ret As Range
Dim RangeToCopy As Range

Set RangeToCopy = Range("C2:F2")
'
' PasteMacro Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+m
'
    Set Ret = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please select a range where you want to paste", Type:=8)
    If Not Ret Is Nothing Then

        RangeToCopy.Copy Destination:=Cells(Ret.Row, RangeToCopy.Column).Resize(1, RangeToCopy.Columns.Count)

        Ret.Resize(1, RangeToCopy.Columns.Count).Calculate

            Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Excellent. It now calculates the entire range which is pasted. Cheers Ron.

Answer (score 0):

In your current code, it's obvious you are only calculating a specific range.

```
Range("C1:F1").Copy Destination:=Ret

        Ret.Calculate
```

So, that `Ret` change it to the entire row range.